# Duplicate KieServerMDB in porting to a new server

Tags: jboss, jbpm, drools-kie-server

I am moving my working laptop configuration of JBPM running atop JBoss EAP 7.3 to a test server running the same configuration. Business Central and my SQL Server JDBC are deployed seem to work on the test server.  However, in

- compressing

  placing in git repo

  retrieving from Git repo

  decompressing my kie-server.war

I am seeing

```
0:01:21,314 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "kie-server.war")])
 - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-server.war\".PARSE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"kie-serve
r.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYEE0040: A component named 'KieServerMDB' is already defined in this module"}}
10:01:21,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "kie-server.war" (runtime-name : "kie-server.war")
10:01:21,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "business-central.war" (runtime-name : "business-central.war")
10:01:21,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-server.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "kie-server.war"
```

during server startup.  The  bean is defined in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml - but where else could it be defined?

```
 <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <ejb-name>KieServerMDB</ejb-name>
    <message-driven-descriptor>
      <destination-jndi-name>jms/KIE.SERVER.REQUEST</destination-jndi-name>
      <connection-factory-jndi-name>jms/cf/KIE.SERVER.REQUEST</connection-factory-jndi-name>
    </message-driven-descriptor>
    <resource-description>
      <res-ref-name>org.kie.server.jms.KieServerMDB/factory</res-ref-name>
      <jndi-name>jms/cf/KIE.SERVER.RESPONSE</jndi-name>
    </resource-description>
  </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this resolved.  In my porting my code to a new server an combining it with RedHat code several JARs were duplicated.